# Using Silverlight with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, silverlight, model-view-controller, user-controls, view

Could someone point me in the right direction of putting Silverlight User Controls on my Ruby on Rails application's views?

Answer (score 0):

Huh, you can interact with RoR from Silverlight by web services or JS, i think.
What you mean 'putting SL user controls on RoR app'? You can include `.xap` into html page and Silverlight has the ability to use JS on a page where he is placed.

Answer (score 0):

You neet to use IronRuby.

Documentation about using Silverlight with Iron Ruby is here: http://ironruby.net/browser/docs.html

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have Silverlight application on the page (and this page is written with RoR) then you can simply embedded `.xap` file into the page - you can do it using [object tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189089%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or [JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265155%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (Silverlight.js file)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick tutorial - haven't tried it yet, but seems good.
http://techblogging.wordpress.com/2008/03/26/using-silverlight-with-rubyonrails/